# Keep element history when relocating elements between UCM components

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

For a variety of terrible yet neccessary reasons, our project needs to split a UCM VOB into multiple UCM VOBs. We currently have the follow VOB/component structure:

```
/vobs/companyA/teamA/dev
/vobs/companyA/teamB/dev
/vobs/companyB/teamC/dev
```

We are restructuring into the following structure:

```
/vobs/teamA/dev
/vobs/teamB/dev
/vobs/teamC/dev
```

Is there any way to move/relocate the elements to the new components in the new VOB **and** retain the elements' history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to do that is [`cleartool relocate`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_relo.htm), and its man page explicitly mentions:

> Note: You cannot use relocate in a UCM component VOB or PVOB. Before you perform any relocate operation, read the relocate reference page.

So it is best to select the last meaningful baselines, and 'clearfsimport' their content (at least the right subset) in the new vobs, in order to recreate those baselines.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I had read that man page and was hoping there was some SCM wizardry that could be done to get around it and do the equivalent of a relocate. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian: yes, that is one limit of the UCM model (which has been pretty much lifted with the successor of ClearCase: RTC Jazz source control: https://jazz.net/library/article/126##How_do_I_move_a_resource_to_another_component).

Comment: @Brian: for UCM, the key is to not loose too much time with it, import the relevant baselines only, and keep the initial component accessible for archive and legacy history exploration.