# Clearcase 7.1.2, VOB Splitting

Tags: batch-file, clearcase

We have a current set up of VOB such that source code and documents reside in the same VOB.
To reduce the VOB download time we now want to move the documents to a new VOB, so that only the code part remain in the old VOB.

Since there are lot of folders and files, its not possible to manually relocate each file/folder.

To do this, we need to write a script which will detect file types by their extension and move file types such as .doc,.pdf, .txt to the new VOB.

VOB server is Windows Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.

I'm a novice!
Can someone help me out with the script?

Thanks
Nush

Comment: Do you mean VOB downtime? Why do you want to reduce VOB downtime? backups?

Comment: I meant the time it takes to download a VOB. More the number of files, more the VOB size.

Answer (score 0):

The process would involve [`cleartool relocate`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_relocate.htm): see "[Relocating elements to another VOB](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/vob-relo-mv.htm)".

The best practice is to:

- group all the right elements you want to relocate in one folder (`cleartool move`)
- remocate that folder

It is best if what you want to split is cleanly group is one folder structure.

Note that relocate [wouldn't work if you are using ClearCase UCM though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024597/6309).
See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/2786.html):

> The reason for this restriction is immutable baselines: if an element has ever been in a baseline, it can never be moved to another place; the baseline needs to know where to look for it. So a UCM element really can't be relocated.