# ClearCase Copying an entire element

Tags: clearcase

Is there any way I can copy an entire element from one VOB to another VOB in clearcase?
i.e including labels and other metadata.

Thanks
Nush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650271/6309) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25051622/6309), only the [relocate command](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_relocate.htm) does that.

It works for the element itself, but might not for common elements you might already have created in the destination Vob.